# Down-sampling a signal after convolution

Tags: filters, wavelet

I was trying to understand more about image compression using the Wavelet transform and I got quite confused about the down-sampling step. I took a picture from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_wavelet_transform) for reference:

[image]

At each step a signal (which can be a line or a column from the image) is convoluted with a low-pass filter **g** and a high-pass filter **h**. After this, the next step would be to down-sample the resulting convolutions by a factor of two.

Going further to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting_scheme#Generalized_lifting) Wikipedia page about the lifting scheme I can see that we can't keep the same indexes for both convoluted signals (we must keep an even index for a convolution and an odd one for the other convolution).

Why is this the case? Why can't we simply keep the even index (or the odd index) when down-sampling for both convolutions?